# PHP: 2objects in 1 variable. Trying to get second object

Tags: php, variables, object

I have a variable (page) which contains 2 page objects.

print_r of the page-variable:

```
  Page Object
(
    [blocksAliasedFromMasterCollection:protected] =&gt; 
    [cID] =&gt; 233
    [attributes:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
        )


)
Page Object
(
    [blocksAliasedFromMasterCollection:protected] =&gt; 
    [cID] =&gt; 234
    [attributes:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
        )



)
{"rel":"SITEMAP","name":"something","cID":"234"}
```

How do I get the cID of the second page object?

Comment: We don't know, because this output is definitely not what `print_r` of a single variable produces and it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use below code

```
if $data contains the objects then
$i=0;
foreach($data as $ar)
{
    if(++$i==2)
    {
       echo $ar->cID;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code gave me an error : something about expecting '(' after if. anyway, I made a mistake and i got it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a single variable, you have an array. You can access all of the elements using indices.

```
$obj1 = $page[0]; // get first object
$obj2 = $page[1]; // get second object\
```

You can then use the object as normal:

`$obj2->method();` or `$obj2->property;`

Comment: When trying this i get a fatal error: Cannot use object of type Page as array in....

Answer (score 0):

The print_r I posted was as stated by Jon incorrect.

What happened was that the function with the print_r in it was called 2 times. That is why the page object was printed 2 times and not in the same variable.

After putting up a check that the function was running for the 2nd time, I got the correct page object.